Why does the execution plan for a query changes after executing the query?
I'm playing around with DB2 LUW 11.5.8 using the IMDB dataset and noticed some (for me) unexpected query plan behavior.
Consider this query:
SELECT primary_title, title_type, average_rating
FROM title_basics LEFT JOIN title_ratings
ON title_basics.id = title_ratings.title_id
WHERE start_year = 2028;

Initially, the optimizer chose a plan using the clustering index on start_year and an RIDSCN with estimated about 40,000 rows (actual: 6 rows, no ratings).
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Explain Plan                                                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID | Operation                              |                         Rows | Cost|
| 1 | RETURN                                 |                              | 8953|
| 2 |  HSJOIN (RIGHT)                        |               44984 of 44984 | 8953|
| 3 |   TBSCAN TITLE_RATINGS                 | 1470798 of 1470798 (100.00%) | 7626|
| 4 |   FETCH TITLE_BASICS                   |               44984 of 44984 | 1271|
| 5 |    RIDSCN                              |               44984 of 44984 |  179|
| 6 |     SORT (UNIQUE)                      |               44984 of 44984 |  179|
| 7 |      IXSCAN IX_TITLE_BASICS_START_YEAR |  44984 of 10653157 (   .42%) |  162|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

After running detailed statistics:
CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('RUNSTATS ON TABLE DB2INST1.TITLE_BASICS ' ||
                       'WITH DISTRIBUTION ON COLUMNS (START_YEAR NUM_FREQVALUES 200) ' ||
                       'AND DETAILED INDEXES ALL');

The optimizer switched to a more efficient plan using IXSCAN + FETCH and a NLJOIN with correct row estimates (6 rows).
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Explain Plan                                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID | Operation                            |                    Rows | Cost|
| 1 | RETURN                               |                         |  107|
| 2 |  NLJOIN (LEFT)                       |                  6 of 0 |  107|
| 3 |   FETCH TITLE_BASICS                 |        6 of 6 (100.00%) |   20|
| 4 |    IXSCAN IX_TITLE_BASICS_START_YEAR | 6 of 10654942 (   .00%) |   14|
| 5 |   FETCH TITLE_RATINGS                |        0 of 0 (   .00%) |   14|
| 6 |    IXSCAN SQL240820171842720         |  0 of 1470798 (   .00%) |   14|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+

However, after a single execution of the query, the plan reverts to the original RIDSCN approach with inflated estimates.
This behavior also affects other queries on the same predicate. For example:
SELECT primary_title, title_type
FROM title_basics
WHERE start_year = 2028;

Also reverts to using RIDSCN with overestimated rows (40,000 vs actual 6).

Why does the query plan changes after a single execution despite having collected detailed statistics?
Why are the statistics no longer used, even for other queries?


What happens if you runstats with distribution and sampled detailed indexes all on both tables?
